# Отслеживание клика по ссылке

Tags: jquery

Всем привет. Возник небольшой вопрос. Необходимо отследить клик по ссылке и после клика выполнить определенную функцию.

Код написал такой, в опере он со своей задей справляется отлично, но вот в мозилле и хроме некоторые из ссылок не понимает, хотя выборка идет по атрибуту href.

Сами ссылки подгружаются с js библиотеки (рекламная ротация баннеров).

```
var link = $('a[href*=marketgid]');
$(link).click(function(){
    //запуск кода после клика
});
```

Пример сгенерированной ссылки, которую видит пользователь.

```
<a href="http://marketgid.com/ghits/1657363/i/765/0/pp/1/6/k/?k=25898faSMTM1NTYwNTY0NjU5MDI1ODk4NjY1fbSMThifcSMTNiYTA2NDljZmU%3DfdSMTNiYTA2NGJlMDE%3DfeSfgSZmI%3DfhSMTE3fiSZTM%3DfjSfkSYzE%3DflSfmSZGQ%3DfnSY2E%3DfoSfpSMTE3fqSMjA%3DfrSfsSaHR0cDovL3BpcmF0Y2EvYWRzLnBocA%3D%3DftSaHR0cDovL3BpcmF0Y2EvYWRzLnBocA%3D%3DfuSfvSNGI%3DfwSZmI%3DfxSMWZifySZTI%3DfzSMWE0" target="_blank" style="display: block;" rel="3"><img class="mcimage765" width="200" height="200" src="http://imgg.dt00.net/1657/1657363_vb.jpg"></a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если ссылки "подгружаются", то, возможно, вам поможет следующая конструкция:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a[href*=marketgid]', function(e){
    // ваши махинации тут
})
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. Ваш вариант работает как надо :)

Answer (score 2):

Внимательно читайте [документацию](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/). Значение селектора необходимо заключать в двойные кавычки (если снаружи стоят одинарные):

```
var link = $('a[href*="marketgid"]');
```

Comment: двойные или одинарные - результат один и тот же :) мозилла не на всех ссылках понимает js выборку. часть ссылок работает, часть нет

Comment: Какая версия jQuery, какая Firefox?

Comment: jQuery библиотека 1,8,2 мозилла тоже последней версии

Answer (score -1):

onclick="" в `<a>` добавьте и js код функции который делает то, что вы хотите чтобы происходило.

Comment: Интересно узнать к чему минусы в данном ответе.

Comment: @Сергей потому что ваш ответ никаким боком не причастен к вопросу.

Comment: Вообще то вопрос был "Необходимо отследить клик по ссылке и после клика выполнить определенную функцию". В ссылке я такого атрибута не вижу, поэтому я не понимаю почему вы считаете мой ответ не причастен к вопросу.

Comment: а Вы первый пост внимательно прочитайте как и от куда берутся ссылки

Comment: @Сергей по вашим рассуждениям можно и C# сюда прилепить :-)

Comment: а что мешает добавить то? я не вижу проблемы. то что вы не желаете этого делать это другой вопрос.